# The .clear meta-command in the Node.js REPL

Tags: javascript, node.js, read-eval-print-loop

Is the `.clear` meta-command **exactly** the same as the `.break` meta-command, or is it a variation of it? I know that they can both be used to break out of a `...` prompt (an indication that you haven't yet finished your command) without exiting the REPL, as can be done by hitting `CTRL+C`. But are there any fundamental differences between `.clear` and `.break`?

I have read in numerous places that in the node.js REPL, the `.clear` meta-command is meant to wipe out any variables or closures that you might have in memory without the need to restart the REPL.

Is the expected behavior such that I can declare a variable, run the `.clear` command, and call that variable again, finding it empty/non-declared? In my use of the `.clear` command, I haven't found that to work.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The `.break` and `.clear` commands behave differently depending on if you started the REPL from the `node` command, or used `repl.start()`.

When using the `node` command, `.clear` is just an alias for `.break`. But if you start the REPL from `repl.start()`, `.clear` will then clear the local context as you are expecting, and `.break` behaves as stated.

This is what `.help` looks like from a REPL instance started from `node`:

```
.break  Sometimes you get stuck, this gets you out
.clear  Alias for .break
.exit   Exit the repl
.help   Show repl options
.load   Load JS from a file into the REPL session
.save   Save all evaluated commands in this REPL session to a file
```

And this is what it looks like when started programmatically:

```
.break  Sometimes you get stuck, this gets you out
.clear  Break, and also clear the local context
.exit   Exit the repl
.help   Show repl options
.load   Load JS from a file into the REPL session
.save   Save all evaluated commands in this REPL session to a file
```

Using `.clear` in a REPL started with `repl.start()` will also show this:

```
Clearing context...
```

Here's an example of using the REPL programmatically:

```
var repl = require('repl');
var str = 'We can pass variables into a context.';

repl.start().context.str2 = str;
```

After this, we have a CLI open. If we type `str2` then you will get the contents of `str`. If you clear the context, then `str2` will no longer exist inside the context.

Comment: What a great answer! So thorough! :)

Comment: Would you mind providing me with an example of how REPL can be started programmatically so I can test this out? Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

**Thanks @hexacyanide for your answer!**

And these are two screenshots.

In the first screenshot, REPL was instantiated programmatically (by running the `repltest.js` script), so the `.clear` meta-command clears the variable from the memory. You can also see that the `.help` command returns a different behavior for `.clear` when REPL is instantiated by a script.

In the second screenshot, `.clear` has a different behavior however. Here REPL is instantiated directly via command (simply by running node in `CMD`). In this case, the variables are not cleared from the memory, and the `.help` command only tells us that `.clear` is an alias for `.break`.

[image: instantiated programmatically]
[image: instantiated via command]

Thanks again hexacyanide for clarifying this.